# how to perform windows level task like ctrl+s using selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

here i want to open a web page and press ctrl+s to save it as the title indicated and press enter.It does open the web page but do nothing what should i fix or change ?

here is my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time

s = Service("msedgedriver.exe")
driver = webdriver.Edge(service=s)
driver.get("https://www.amazon.com/s?i=toys-and-games&bbn=165793011&rh=n%3A165793011%2Cp_36%3A-3000&s=price-desc-rank&page=5&pd_rd_r=5b11ddec-0e7d-4f57-aa26-23a6f01cf651&pd_rd_w=4XJq3&pd_rd_wg=iijv6&pf_rd_p=c98be8e8-690d-4b63-9ae8-c3ee54bc3c66&pf_rd_r=JB98C7R5W79QQY8KAEM8&qid=1686138425&rnid=386491011&ref=sr_pg_5")
time.sleep(5)
actions = ActionChains(driver)
actions.key_down(Keys.CONTROL).send_keys('s').key_up(Keys.CONTROL).perform()
actions.send_keys('Amazon.html').send_keys(Keys.ENTER).perform()
driver.quit()
print('done')
```

Answer (score 0):

Selenium doesn't support interactions with OS-level dialogs like the "Save As" dialog.

If you want to save the page's HTML, you can just get the page source directly using Selenium:

```
s = Service("msedgedriver.exe")
driver = webdriver.Edge(service=s)
driver.get("https://www.amazon.com/s?i=toys-and-games&bbn=165793011&rh=n%3A165793011%2Cp_36%3A-3000&s=price-desc-rank&page=5&pd_rd_r=5b11ddec-0e7d-4f57-aa26-23a6f01cf651&pd_rd_w=4XJq3&pd_rd_wg=iijv6&pf_rd_p=c98be8e8-690d-4b63-9ae8-c3ee54bc3c66&pf_rd_r=JB98C7R5W79QQY8KAEM8&qid=1686138425&rnid=386491011&ref=sr_pg_5")
time.sleep(5)
html = driver.page_source
with open('Amazon.html', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    f.write(html)
driver.quit()
print('done')
```

But if you want to download all assets, u can execute `wget` tool with the help of `subprocess`. We will try to replicate the action of pressing CTRL + S as closely as possible, but depending on the specifics of the website, the result may not be identical.

1. Download `wget` from [here](https://eternallybored.org/misc/wget/) if you are a Windows user
2. On Linux, run this command `sudo apt-get install wget`

Then try this:

```
import subprocess

# replace this with the path to your wget executable
wget_path = '/usr/bin/wget' #On Linux the path would be '/usr/bin/wget'. On Windows, wherever you have installed it

url = "https://www.amazon.com/s?i=toys-and-games&bbn=165793011&rh=n%3A165793011%2Cp_36%3A-3000&s=price-desc-rank&page=5&pd_rd_r=5b11ddec-0e7d-4f57-aa26-23a6f01cf651&pd_rd_w=4XJq3&pd_rd_wg=iijv6&pf_rd_p=c98be8e8-690d-4b63-9ae8-c3ee54bc3c66&pf_rd_r=JB98C7R5W79QQY8KAEM8&qid=1686138425&rnid=386491011&ref=sr_pg_5"

# the directory where you want to save the webpage
output_dir = './'

subprocess.call([wget_path, '--recursive', '--no-clobber', '--page-requisites', '--html-extension', '--convert-links', '--restrict-file-names=windows', '--domains', 'amazon.com', '--no-parent', url], cwd=output_dir)
```